# User control data binding winrt

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am facing problem of data binding in user control.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource
                x:Name="itemsViewSource"
                Source="{Binding Items}"
                d:Source="{Binding AllGroups[0].Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Source>
                    <local:SampleDataSource />
                </Binding.Source>
            </Binding>
        </UserControl.DataContext>

     <StackPanel Margin="20,60">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}">Categories</TextBlock>
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Title}" />


                </ListBox>

            </StackPanel>
```

The Title property binding is showing in the XAML designer window but nothing is showing during execution of the program.
I am using the default flipview layout in which there is a "Title" in SampleDataSource.cs file

Answer (score 0):

The "d:" prefix is for properties that you would define solely for use in the designer, so you should try replacing "d:Source" with "Source".

Comment: the `Source` is already defined, `Source="{Binding Items}"`. Why he need to change `d:Source` to `Source`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. What is your DataContext then? Does it have an Items property? Make sure to check the VS Output window (Ctrl+W,O) to see if any binding errors pop up.

Answer (score 0):

did you fix following line

```
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

it's defined at the top where all the page declarations are.

Also

```
Source="{Binding Items}"
```

is referring to a `List` named `Items` in your `DataContext`.